# Date and time data extraction from a hex dump

Tags: binary-analysis, binary

I am trying to retrieve date and time data from a hex dump. I found following entries that has entry id and date time information in it. But, I am not sure about which offset it is.

```
60 03 00 00 00 F1 16 CE 18 23 8E E1 00 01 9E  ->  2011.10.29 x.x.x
38 05 00 00 00 89 70 B0 83 34 8E E1 00 01 4E  ->  2011.10.30 x.x.x
1A 06 00 00 00 89 0F 9E 71 3C 8E E1 00 01 12  ->  2011.10.31 x.x.x
24 07 00 00 00 03 45 29 A2 71 8E E1 00 01 28  ->  2011.11.02 x.x.x
1A 00 00 00 00 41 E7 A2 6E 22 DA E1 00 01 12  ->  2014.06.22 22.39.x
1A 01 00 00 00 B9 47 48 73 22 DA E1 00 01 12  ->  2014.06.22 22.40.x
```

I already tried with last 8 bytes with different epoch. For an example,
with `48 73 22 DA E1 00 01 12`, in little endian arrangement (epoch Jan,1,1), I got `4112-01-16 18:42:48.674601`.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335359/extracting-date-and-time-from-a-binary-data-string-using) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814588/covert-binary-64-bit-timestamp-offset-from-the-gps-epoch-to-python-datetime-obje) questions similar to mine and tried their methods. But, still I can't retrieve the right data.

Also, could you please give me a reference to book that deals with binary data extraction like this?

Comment: And you don't have any code that deals with the data as to extract the clues about the data format from that?

Answer (score 6):

the 64 bit value at offset 5 is the number of microseconds since the year 0:

Use this perl script to verify:

```
use POSIX;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/(.*\S)\s+->\s+(.*\S)/) {
        my ($hex, $date)= ($1,$2);

        # convert date to unix timestamp
        $date =~ s/x/0/g;
        my @f= reverse split /[. ]/, $date;
        $f[4]--;  # correct month for mktime
        $f[5]-=1900; # correct year for mktime
        my $unixtime= POSIX::mktime(@f);

        # extract qword starting at byte 5
        $hex =~ s/\s//g;
        my ($lo,$hi)= unpack("VV", substr(pack("H*", $hex), 5, 8));
        $value= $hi*0x100000000+$lo;

        printf("0x%x/1000000-%d = %d\n", $value, $unixtime, $value/1000000-$unixtime);
    }
}
__DATA__
60 03 00 00 00 F1 16 CE 18 23 8E E1 00 01 9E  ->  2011.10.29 x.x.x
38 05 00 00 00 89 70 B0 83 34 8E E1 00 01 4E  ->  2011.10.30 x.x.x
1A 06 00 00 00 89 0F 9E 71 3C 8E E1 00 01 12  ->  2011.10.31 x.x.x
24 07 00 00 00 03 45 29 A2 71 8E E1 00 01 28  ->  2011.11.02 x.x.x
1A 00 00 00 00 41 E7 A2 6E 22 DA E1 00 01 12  ->  2014.06.22 22.39.x
1A 01 00 00 00 B9 47 48 73 22 DA E1 00 01 12  ->  2014.06.22 22.40.x
```

resulting in this output:

```
0xe18e2318ce16f1/1000000-1319839200 = 62168311951
0xe18e3483b07089/1000000-1319925600 = 62168300358
0xe18e3c719e0f89/1000000-1320015600 = 62168244415
0xe18e71a2294503/1000000-1320188400 = 62168300062
0xe1da226ea2e741/1000000-1403469540 = 62168241639
0xe1da22734847b9/1000000-1403469600 = 62168241657
```

62168241657/86400/365.2422 =  1970.03477142853579229222 years